# Cipher /w:Foldername Usage Vs Drive utilization

Tags: filesystems, disk-cleanup

I have 300 GB Filestream folder.

Below is the exact command I ran:

cipher /w:M:\Tech\Database_FS\

I am trying to use Cipher /w to wipe off any unused space in the above folder. Instead of cleaning up space it started eating up existing drive space almost 400 GB. After process , it is doing nothing and revert back to original size. Along with a temp folder.

My understaning is : Filestream cleanup is only by Garbage Collection process. Even if we try Cipher /w: foldernamepath we will not be able to cleanup space. Am I correct ?

Kindly advise on above , why it uses existing drive storage instead of wiping internal drive data in folder.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the exact command you ran?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment to include this vital required information necessary to answer your question.  However, the disk usage increasing is normal, that is the only way you can overwrite data.  What does your question have to do with the built-in disk cleanup tool?

Comment: I edited my question Ramhound. Please do let me know if any info I missed to update.